# Problem with overflowing unicode characters in JTextPane (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtextpane

I want to use unicode characters to visualise playing cards for a poker game. I print them in JTextPane on seperate lines. As you can see on the first image they tend to overflow to other lines sometimes. I am outputing the cards using the same method, so it is really weird that it happens only sometimes. It's totally random.

Every card has the same style set through SimpleAttributeSet. It look like the line height for the cards is smaller then it should be. So I was thinking that the Swing may have some bad support for unicode characters so I added an 'M' character between the cards with the same style as the cards. After that everything seemed to work fine.

This is an example how I print out the cards (cards are printed in a loop):

```
StyledDocument doc = jTextPane.getStyledDocument();

doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: \n", attributeSet);

doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), " \n" , attributeSetForCards);
```

Cards are sometimes overflowing from their lines:
[image: Cards are sometimes overflowing from their lines]

Here you can see they are correctly outputed:
[image: Here you can see they are correctly outputed]

Code below is the example of that bug, but the bug occure just sometimes. I noticed that Thread.sleep() has some inpact on it, because a propability of that happening increased with this command. As you can see in the code below, there is no Thread.sleep() command and the bug appears anyway.

(I changed the cards unicode for letter "M")

Here is code example :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class StackOverflowProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributeSet, 100);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);        

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(textPane);

        frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int x = 0;

        while (x < 100) {
            x++;
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: " + "\n", keyWord);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "M", attributeSet);
                if (i > 1) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.BLACK);
                }
            }

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", keyWord);

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: " + "\n", keyWord);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "M", attributeSet);
            }

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", keyWord);

        }
    }


}
```

### Alternate code:(?)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class StackOverflowProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadLocationException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1500, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributeSet, 100);
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attributeSet, getFontFamily());
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(textPane);

        frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String[][] obrazkyKariet = new String[4][14];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 14; ii++) {
            obrazkyKariet[0][ii] = new String(Character.toChars(ii + 127137));
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 14; ii++) {
            obrazkyKariet[1][ii] = new String(Character.toChars(ii + 127153));
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 14; ii++) {
            obrazkyKariet[2][ii] = new String(Character.toChars(ii + 127169));
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 14; ii++) {
            obrazkyKariet[3][ii] = new String(Character.toChars(ii + 127185));
        }

        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: " + "\n", keyWord);

        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == 3) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);
                }
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), obrazkyKariet[i][j], attributeSet);
            }
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", keyWord);
        }
    }

    public static String getFontFamily() {
        Font[] fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts();
        for (Font font : fonts) {
            if (font.canDisplay(127137)) {
                System.out.println("First compatible font: " + font.getFamily());
                return font.getFamily();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to make graphical application in java, read about Graphics class.

Comment: Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I edited it and I added the code example.

Comment: *"the code example"* Yes but 'the' code examples is *not* an MRE!

Comment: What you mean "it is not an MRE" ? The bug occure in the while loop, with these commands. What other code I'm supposed to post you ?

Comment: Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Now, as to: *"What you mean.."* Well, can you copy / paste that code into a new project in an IDE, compile it *without* changes, and run the code to see the problem? If not, neither can we. An MRE (expansion [mre]) should have that description. There is more to the concept of an MRE (like removing the unnecessary code that is not related to the problem) but hopefully you now have a better idea why it is 'not an MRE' as suggested by camickr.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson That what camickr said was before I had any code here. So I added here code, that actually you can just copy and paste and it will work. I think that all these commands can have some impact on bug, so I think this code is MRE.

Comment: *you can just copy and paste and it will work.* - there are no import statements, there is no class definition, there is no main method. I can't copy/paste/compile/test. If you have already done all that to make sure it does compile and duplicate the problem, then post THAT code. Don't make every individual that reads your question repeat the work you have already done.

Comment: @camickr Cmooon man, really imports ? NetBeans can do this by 1 click. I thought that my class definition and stuff like that would be useless, but ok I can edit it.

Comment: You assume people use an IDE. I don't. That is the point of an MRE. Don't make assumptions. Post code that everybody can test. It doesn't mean people (like me) will have the answer, but at least it makes it easy for them to take a quick look. Also, regarding @AndrewThompson, comment, Is this still an "MRE"? Are the attributes sets necessary do demonstrate the problem, or do they cause the problem. If they don't cause the problem, then all the logic is unnecessary. The point of the MRE is forget about your application and to isolate the problem. Any clue can be helpful.

Comment: @camickr Whatever man, I edited the code and I hope that you will be satisfied. Now can everybody just copy and paste.

Comment: *"Now can everybody just copy and paste."* It's definitely an improvement. But unfortunately the Unicode characters mean a direct cop/paste does not work. (It's something to do with an encoding issue.) I tried altering the source code to make the cards from Unicode code points, but then found that the default font used here for a text pane does not render them, so changed it to use the first font on the system with support for those characters. **Then** because I could not make out which cards were being used, I just put the entire deck in an reduced the number of iterations to 1, to see ..

Comment: .. them render [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpls.png). Ugh .. it is *possible* the problem has something to do with the **font being used.** Here the font chosen was "DejaVu Sans". Would you like me to post the source I'm using, so you can investigate further, there?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. the copy/paste isn't working for my editor. The Unicode characters are not displaying properly. Hope it works for others. Just noticed Andrew already posted this comment with a potential solution .

Comment: @AndrewThompson Guys I noticed that it doesn't matter if I inserting unicode text or just normal letter. So you can replace the unicode text with for example  letter "M" and bug occure anyway.

Comment: @camickr I added the **Alternate code:(?)** at the end of the question (the code that chose DejaVu Sans and rendered correctly). If you're willing to run it, I'd be interested to know: does it also work for you? What font does it use? (The font family should be printed on console.) Fetos: Same questions for you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The console printed: "First compatible font: Dialog".

Comment: *So you can replace the unicode text with for example letter "M" and bug occure anyway* - actually you can edit your posted code an do that. Two people have just told you the code you posted can't be tested as it posted. The point of an MRE is so people can copy/paste/compile/test. People should NOT have to read through multiple comments to find out how to test the posted code to see the problem results. Seems like you are not grasping the concept of an MRE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - worked for me and it used the 'Dialog" font as well. Windows 10 doesn't have the "DejaVu Sans".

Comment: @camickr Sorry for that, I'm new here, I have to learn a lot. I modified the code again and changed the unicode for letter "M".

Comment: @camickr *"Windows 10 doesn't have the "DejaVu Sans"."* Huh.. I have 'Windows 10 Home'. Must have picked it up from MS Office or something. (shrug) *"worked for me"* Nothing like an 'MRE' that isn't an 'E' of the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing is single threaded.

So the creation of all Swing components and updates to the components or its model must be done on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`, otherwise random problems can appear.

What appears to be happening here is that the Document has not been completely updated before another `insertString(…)` method is invoked and some text is not being inserted into the proper location in the Document.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT.

So the solution is to place your code for execution on the `EDT`. The code should be something like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class StackOverflowProblem {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws Exception
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        SimpleAttributeSet attributeSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();

        StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributeSet, 100);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(textPane);

        frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int x = 0;

        while (x < 100) {
            x++;
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: " + "\n", keyWord);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "M", attributeSet);
                if (i > 1) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(attributeSet, Color.BLACK);
                }
            }

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", keyWord);

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "Karty na stole: " + "\n", keyWord);

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "M", attributeSet);
            }

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n", keyWord);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
                catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `invokeLater(…)` places the code on the `EDT`.

Comment: Well it looks like you solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help and your patience with me.